# OSGI Bundle implementing JPA Using DataNucleus 4.0.0 Release

Tags: jpa, osgi, classnotfoundexception, datanucleus, apache-servicemix

I am trying to implement JPA using DataNucleus in an OSGI Environment (Apache ServiceMix). I am following the guide mentioned here - http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/osgi.html (Section under Name "JPA and OSGi") 
As per the documentation here I am using the DataNucleus JPA jar. So I have Deployed this Jar on ServiceMix as follows -

osgi:install mvn:org.datanucleus/datanucleus-jpa/2.1.7

osgi:start bundleId

As this jar export the persistence provider,I have correctly changed the provider in my persistence.xml file to be org.datanucleus.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl (which is exported by the above bundle) rather than usual org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl which is in a normal J2EE JPA APP.

I also have the DataNucleus Core Bundle running on my ServiceMix, which was installed on my ServiceMix using the following -

osgi:install mvn:org.datanucleus/datanucleus-core/4.0.0-release

osgi:start bundleId

Please Note: I donot have the datanucleus-api-jpa bundle running on my ServiceMix, as per the documentation, the datanucleus-jpa bundle would export the necessary classes and hence datanucleus-api-jpa bundle would not be required.

At runtime, I am getting the following error Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration not found by org.datanucleus.jpa [261]

What I have noticed is that the DataNucleus Core version 4.0.0-release does not have this class, but this class exists in all previous releases (3.2.15).

I cannot deploy DataNucleus Core Version 3.2.XX onto my ServiceMix, because I have other bundles using DataNucleus Core 4.0.0-release and having both is not an option because of Singleton Creation problems.

Please let me know, if you need me to post my code, I will do so. 
Please help

Cheers,
Abhijit

Comment: Why are you using "datanucleus-jpa" v2.1.x when you say you want to use DataNucleus v4.x ??? v2.x has not been supported for a long time.

Comment: A work around to load implementing class found inside the META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider is to export the persistence provider as OSGi service. This is what the DataNucleus JPA jar does which is version 2.1.7 the latest version.

Comment: No it is NOT the "latest version". It is an ancient version. "datanucleus-api-jpa" is the currently supported artifact, as shown by reading the documentation

Comment: Sorry I am not referring to datanucleus-api-jpa but I am referring to datanucleus-jpa artifact

Comment: As I've already said ... that is ANCIENT. That artifact is not used now, and datanucleus-api-jpa IS (i.e it replaced it). All of that can be found easily enough in the documentation

Comment: let me try with datanucleus-api-jpa thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conclusion, you are using incorrect/invalid jars. "datanucleus-jpa" was removed back in v2 of DataNucleus. All recent versions using "datanucleus-api-jpa" (or "datanucleus-api-jdo" if using JDO). A simple download of the DataNucleus zip file for 4.0.x would show this very clearly.